# Bizarre function that generalizes the inclusion-exclusion formula for $\pi(t) - \pi(\sqrt{t + 1})$. For all reals $t\geq 5$, the function is non-zero

Tags: group-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, analytic-number-theory, inclusion-exclusion

> **Conjecture.**  The following arithmetic function is never zero, for any $t \in \Bbb{R}$, and $t \geq 5$:
> $$
> g(t) := \sum_{d \mid p_n\#}(-1)^{\omega(d)}\left\lfloor\frac{t}{d}\right\rfloor|G_d|
> $$
> where $G_d = \{ x \in \Bbb{Z}/d : x^2 = 1\pmod d\}$, and where $n(x) := \pi(\sqrt{x + 1})$ varies with $x$.

What it's related to is the prime-counter function $\pi(x)$.  If you were to replace each of the groups of 2nd roots of unity with the trivial group then you'll recover:

$$
\sum_{d \mid p_n\#} (-1)^{\omega(d)}\left\lfloor\frac{t}{d}\right \rfloor = \pi(t) - \pi(\sqrt{t+ 1}) 
$$

This is well-known and even on the Wikipedia page for the prime counter.  This is a generalization of that function, clearly.  What it counts,  I'm not sure.  It doesn't count quite the twin prime averages.  However, it does show up in that context.

Comment: I was thinking could we some how do this via induction on group order and taking normal subgroups etc? All the groups are abelian, so...

Comment: For that to work.  The base case is clear: PNT or Bertrand's would work to show there's always a prime in $(\sqrt{t + 1}, t]$.  So the base case corresponds to the trivial groups.  We need to build our way up to the $G_d$ in a manner of speaking.

Comment: When $d$ is odd, it is clear that $|G_d|=2^{\omega(d)}$, and when $d$ is even, $|G_d|=2^{\omega(d)-1}$.

Comment: If you look up any texts in sieve methods, you will find that this function tending to infinity as $x\to\infty$ is equivalent to the twin prime conjecture

Comment: @TravorLZH Everyone knows though that the standard sieve techniques cannot be sufficient to prove twin primes.  Might I ask why this formula never shows up in analytic number theory without mention of sieving?  Also, the only sieving I did just to derive it is the basic Sieve-of-Eratosthenes, which of course everyone knows even those who aren't working in Sieve Theory.   In other words, granted it is derived using a Sieve, but once that's said and done, I'm looking for non-Sieving techniques.  After all, the only part of Sieving we're using is to pick a summation lower bound.

Comment: Any technique applied to study these kinds of sums are considered something belonging to sieve theory. Eratosthenes is just a starting point.

Comment: @TravorLZH do you know a book that has this exact formula in it?  Trouble is, I look into sieve books and don't find such a formula (typically), or they express it in much less succinct form.

Comment: _Sieve Methods_ by Halberstam & Richert is the exact book for you. They let $\mathcal A$ denote an arbitrary subset of integers, $\mathcal A_d$ denote the multiples of $d$ in $\mathcal A$, and $\mathcal P$ be a set of prime numbers. Then the number of integers in $\mathcal A$ free of divisors in $\mathcal P\cap[2,z)$ is $$\sum_{d|P(z)}\mu(d)|\mathcal A_d|$$where$$P(z)=\prod_{p\in\mathcal P\cap[2,z)}p$$

Comment: @TravorLZH Why not study these from other perspectives?

Comment: What do you mean specifically by "other perspectives"? The book provides various methods to give upper bound and lower bound estimations for the sum described in my previous reply. Studying the sum without reading these existing works is pretty likely to result in re-inventing wheels.